# How to change the wallpaper of pc or mobile through a flask website?

Tags: javascript, python, web, flask, progressive-web-apps

I am beginner in web development and making a flask website which fetches quotes through an API and display it on the screen. But, I also want to enable the user to add this quote in some image format as their wallpaper in PC and mobile devices(and also lock screen) and change it weekly or monthly automatically(of course with their permissions).

Is there any way in flask or Javascript to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't change the background of your PC from a web app.

The browser has a sandbox for your web app which it cannot leave. From within this sandbox it is not able to change any system settings, write or read files from the user's computer.

Comment: What about progressive web apps. Can I do it in a PWA?

Comment: No, a PWA is still just a web app. It has the same restrictions.